# React Native - Is correct to render stateful components in FlatLists?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is it "common" to render stateful components inside FlatLists?

I have been experiencing some problems due to Virtualization... some components are unmounted and then, their stateful data is lost.

For example, if you constantly add items to the beginning of your data, and you render it inside a FlatList with numColumns > 1, all your list's components will be re-mounted (not re-rendered), and the stateful data will be lost.

I have tried to get the same behavior with an endless list, but I don't know how many items it will need to render in order to unmount "old" components.

So... what do you think? Should it be "illegal"?

Check it: https://snack.expo.dev/0emMA550i

And for long lists: https://snack.expo.dev/_4fR4Q2lP